# Object.contentDocument is undefined is IE

Tags: javascript, svg

```
var object = document.getElementById("object");
var svgDocument = object.contentDocument;
var svg = svgDocument.getElementsByTagName('svg');
```

Unable to get property 'getElementsByTagName' of undefined or null reference on last string. How can I select svg element in object tag in IE? 
My HTML

```
<div class="customForm__cell">
    <object id="object" data="/Content/Themes/Default/Images/ltr/icon_url.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
</div>
```

Comment: what's your html can you please share

Comment: @RobertLongson Yes, this code after loading the object and they are in the same domain